# Oracle SQL to get series id

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a table `myTable`.

```
select ID, Timestamp, Value from myTable order by Timestamp
```

returns

| ID | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 2002-03-03T00:34:42 | A |
| 53 | 2002-03-03T00:35:46 | B |
| 21 | 2002-03-03T00:37:02 | A |
| 33 | 2002-03-03T03:12:56 | C |
| 71 | 2002-03-03T10:31:14 | B |
| 16 | 2002-03-03T17:19:21 | A |

I need to divide the rows into series starting with value A. Can anyone write an SQL for a column `Series_ID` returning the ID of the first rows in each series.

| ID | Series_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 42 | 42 |
| 53 | 42 |
| 21 | 21 |
| 33 | 21 |
| 71 | 21 |
| 16 | 16 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `ignore nulls` feature of `lag` function to retrieve ID of previous `'A'` only:

> ```
> with a(ID, ts, value) as (
> select 42, timestamp '2002-03-03 00:34:42', 'A' from dual union all
> select 53, timestamp '2002-03-03 00:35:46', 'B' from dual union all
> select 21, timestamp '2002-03-03 00:37:02', 'A' from dual union all
> select 33, timestamp '2002-03-03 03:12:56', 'C' from dual union all
> select 71, timestamp '2002-03-03 10:31:14', 'B' from dual union all
> select 16, timestamp '2002-03-03 17:19:21', 'A' from dual
> )
> select
>   a.* 
>   , decode(
>     /*Get ID of A*/
>     value, 'A', id,
>     /*else ID of previous A*/
>     lag(decode(value, 'A', id, null))
>       ignore nulls
>       over(order by ts asc)
>   ) as series
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | TS                           | VALUE | SERIES
> -: | :--------------------------- | :---- | -----:
> 42 | 03-MAR-02 00.34.42.000000000 | A     |     42
> 53 | 03-MAR-02 00.35.46.000000000 | B     |     42
> 21 | 03-MAR-02 00.37.02.000000000 | A     |     21
> 33 | 03-MAR-02 03.12.56.000000000 | C     |     21
> 71 | 03-MAR-02 10.31.14.000000000 | B     |     21
> 16 | 03-MAR-02 17.19.21.000000000 | A     |     16
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4b186c597204f59adb3fb18fee47e11a)*

Or similarly, but a bit more readable with `match_recognize`:

> ```
> select *
> from a
> match_recognize (
>   order by ts
>   measures
>     /*ID of the row with value = A
>      for all the rows within a match group
>     */
>     max(a.id) as series
>   all rows per match
>   pattern (a b*)
>   define
>     a as value = 'A',
>     b as lnnvl(value = 'A')
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> TS                           | SERIES | ID | VALUE
> :--------------------------- | -----: | -: | :----
> 03-MAR-02 00.34.42.000000000 |     42 | 42 | A    
> 03-MAR-02 00.35.46.000000000 |     42 | 53 | B    
> 03-MAR-02 00.37.02.000000000 |     21 | 21 | A    
> 03-MAR-02 03.12.56.000000000 |     21 | 33 | C    
> 03-MAR-02 10.31.14.000000000 |     21 | 71 | B    
> 03-MAR-02 17.19.21.000000000 |     16 | 16 | A
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a248778b81c5f22bfbd11387bace3142)*

Answer (score 3):

You can identify the rows that mark the beginning of each group and then just join the table with itself.

For example:

```
with
g as (
  select
    t.*, 
    case when val = 'A' then 1 else 0 end as mk,
    sum(case when val = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by ts) as grp
  from t
)
select a.*, b.id as series_id
from g a
join g b on b.grp = a.grp and b.mk = 1;
```

Result:

```
 ID  TS         VAL  MK  GRP  SERIES_ID 
 --- ---------- ---- --- ---- --------- 
 42  03-MAR-02  A    1   1    42        
 53  03-MAR-02  B    0   1    42        
 21  03-MAR-02  A    1   2    21        
 33  03-MAR-02  C    0   2    21        
 71  03-MAR-02  B    0   2    21        
 16  03-MAR-02  A    1   3    16
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dc8bbae2ec2f28d679c1a226f99414dc).